# How to use Clang static analyzer with a Cortex-M project?

Tags: c++, arm, clang, cortex-m, clang-static-analyzer

I'm developing a "bare-metal" C/C++ application for an ARM Cortex-M based MCU.
I'd like to incorporate the Clang static analyzer to my build system.

So instead of

```
arm-none-eabi-g++ ....
```

I now use

```
scan-build arm-none-eabi-g++ ...
```

This seems to work okay, but I get a bunch of messages about the CMSIS header files and the stuff that I got from the chip manufacturer:

- error: cast from pointer to smaller type 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') loses information

I agree that they **should have** used `uintptr_t` instead of `int32_t` but can't rewrite their entire code base and the CMSIS headers as well. Can I tell `scan-build` that pointers on this platform are actually 32-bit so there is no loss of information?

I tried to tell it to consider which platform I use. But if I use `scan-build --analyzer-target=arm-none-eabi`, I get:

- fatal error: 'cstring' file not found
- error: unknown register name 'vfpcc' in asm

Again, in the CMSIS headers.

My questions are:

- Why can't the analyzer find the `cstring` header when I use `--analyzer-target=arm-none-eabi`?
- How can I tell the analyzer that my pointers are truly 32-bit?
- Why does it give me that error about that unknown register?

Or alternatively:

- How can I silence those warnings for the CMSIS headers?

**EDIT**

I also tried the following suggestion but it didn't work, it resulted in the same errros:

```
scan-build
    --use-cc=/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc
    --use-c++=/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++
    --analyzer-target=arm-none-eabi
    arm-none-eabi-g++ ...
```

Note: I use the *[qbs](http://doc.qt.io/qbs/)* build system, and generated the `scan-build` calls using the `cpp.compilerWrapper` property in my `.qbs` file.

A typical command looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/scan-build --use-cc=/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc --use-c++=/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++ --analyzer-target=arm-none-eabi /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++ -g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -mabi=aapcs -mno-sched-prolog -mabort-on-noreturn -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-builtin -specs=nosys.specs -specs=nano.specs -static -nodefaultlibs -Wdouble-promotion -ggdb -g3 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -pipe -frandom-seed=0x633bf14c -Wdate-time -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fvisibility=default -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wno-unused-function -DS1_USE_SEGGER_RTT -DEFM32WG940F256 -D__HEAP_SIZE=0 -I/home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/dependencies/platform/emdrv/common/inc -I/home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/dependencies/platform/emdrv/config -I/home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/dependencies/platform/emdrv/dmadrv/inc -I/home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/dependencies/platform/emdrv/dmadrv/config -I/home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/dependencies/hardware/kit/common/drivers -I/home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/dependencies/platform/emdrv/gpiointerrupt/inc -I/home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/dependencies/platform/emdrv/nvm/inc -I/home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/dependencies/platform/emdrv/nvm/config -I/home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/dependencies/platform/emdrv/rtcdrv/inc -I/home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/dependencies/platform/emdrv/rtcdrv/config -I/home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/dependencies/platform/emdrv/sleep/inc -I/home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/dependencies/platform/emdrv/spidrv/inc -I/home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/dependencies/platform/emdrv/spidrv/config -I/home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/dependencies/platform/emdrv/uartdrv/inc -I/home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/dependencies/platform/emdrv/uartdrv/config -I/home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/dependencies/platform/emdrv/ustimer/inc -I/home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/dependencies/platform/emdrv/ustimer/config -I/home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/dependencies/platform/emlib/inc -I/home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/dependencies/platform/CMSIS/Include -I/home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/dependencies/platform/Device/SiliconLabs/EFM32WG/Include -I/home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/dependencies/RTT -std=c++0x -o /home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/build-myproject-my-software-arm_none_eabi-Debug/qtc_arm_none_a793425c-debug/myproject-my-software.qtc-arm-none-a793425c.7e216384/.obj/e6c416981c959a66/efm32-serial-port.cpp.o -c /home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/source/utilities/hal/efm32-serial-port.cpp
In file included from /home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/source/utilities/hal/efm32-serial-port.cpp:24:
In file included from /home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/source/utilities/hal/efm32-serial-port.h:27:
In file included from /home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/source/utilities/hal/abstract-serial-port.h:32:
/home/Timur/Projects/MyProject/my-software/source/utilities/hal/../core/callback.h:32:10: fatal error: 'cstddef' file not found
#include <cstddef>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
scan-build: Using '/usr/bin/clang-4.0' for static analysis
scan-build: 0 bugs found.
scan-build: The analyzer encountered problems on some source files.
scan-build: Preprocessed versions of these sources were deposited in '/tmp/scan-build-2017-07-27-194505-8969-1/failures'.
scan-build: Please consider submitting a bug report using these files:
scan-build:   http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/filing_bugs.html
```

Comment: Hi Venemo, did you succeed? I have the same exact problem using the Segger Embedded Studio and a nRF52 DK board.

Comment: @alcor No, I'm still waiting on an answer to this one.

Comment: thanks buddy, still trying here too

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to specify the `use-cc=/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc` flag too : http://blog.canyonbliss.net/static-code-analysis-with-scan-build-while-cross-compiling/

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, it doesn't work, it still gives me the same errors.

Comment: worked for me. With clang 9.0.1 and arm-none-eabi-gcc 9.2.0

Answer (score 1):

The missing "cstring" is because clang do not include STL headers. I had the same issue and adding `-I<path_to_st_includes>` fixed it.

So in my QBS I have something like that:

```
property string repoDir: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/packs"
cpp.includePaths: [
        repoDir + "/arm/CMSIS/4.2.0/CMSIS/Include",
        "C:/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/arm/arm-gnu-toolchain/arm-none-eabi/include/c++/6.3.1",
        "C:/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/arm/arm-gnu-toolchain/arm-none-eabi/include"
        ]
```

For `vfpcc` it seems to be a problem from clang. The Chromium project even had a fix to remove uses of `vfpcc`: https://codereview.chromium.org/411803002/

The only solution I have found so far is to disable the hardware FPU for the static analysis.

One way to do it is to use `-mfpu=none` on clang. But then gcc will complain that `none` is not valid... And since Qt Creator build the project before the analysis, the build will fail and the analysis will not start.

The other way is to define `__SOFTFP__`. This will force `__FPU_USED` to be `0` and disable all the functions that use `vfpcc`.

Comment: Instead of `-mfpu=none` how about `-mfloat-abi=soft`? However I'm not a big fan of this because then the static analysis would be performed on a slightly different variant of the code base than is actually run on the MCU.

Comment: `-mfloat-abi=soft` does not work. I still have errors about `vfpcc`, but I also have new errors about a missing include `bits/c++config.h`. Anyway I agree it is not the best solution, but it seems to be the only solution until clang supports `vfpcc` or `vfpcc` is removed from CMSIS :-/

Comment: About just adding the STL headers like you suggested: is it possible not to use an absolute path, but instead somehow query the default paths from the compiler? I would prefer not to hardwire it.

Comment: I do not know. For me it is a missing feature from Qt Creator and/or QBS. The IDE should make sure to pass the include paths used by gcc to clang.